# Creating specific taxonomy terms the Drush way

Tags: taxonomy-terms, drush

is there a way to create specific taxonomy terms the drush way?

the docs mention only a number argument to generate dummy terms.

http://www.drushcommands.com/drush-7x/devel-generate/generate-terms

i have around 150 terms (city - country (parent) - region (parent)) in one location taxonomy vocabulary. would be great if i can write the syntax in a text editor and use this to populate the vocabulary.

thx for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the taxonomy manager module.

https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager

It allows for mass insertion of terms.

There's also a taxonomy csv module which allows for import/export of taxonomies to file. That might be worth a try too:
https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv

Else you can try and write your own module... But that's a rather tougher route.

Comment: thx for your suggestions! the taxonomy_csv is just what i was looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

For one-offs, a mass insertion module may not be suitable.

Upset that there was no existing simple way to add content in Drush, I created the drush create-content command set, which allows for the one-off creation of vocabularies, nodes and terms.

https://github.com/djcf/drush-create